# select combobox item by value c# in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have the below custom class for my combobox, and i'm trying to programmatically select an item by value.  I'm able to retrieve the item by value using casting, but can't seem to select the item by value.

```
string test2 = ((GetAcctNum)_comboBox.SelectedItem).Value;
```

// casting can retreive the item by value, but how do you select the item by value?

```
public class GetAcctNum
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

I cant use the below solution, because I won't know the text.  I will only know the hidden value that needs to be selected in the combobox.

```
_comboBox.SelectedValue = _comboBox.Items.FindByText("text").Value;
```

Below is how I add the values to the comboBox

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
 {
     while (reader.Read())
    {
       temp = new GetAcctNum();
       temp.Value = reader["AccountID"].ToString();
       temp.Text = reader["AccountNumber"].ToString();  
        getAcctNum.Add(temp);
        rowsAffected++;
   }
 }
//Omitted for brevity//
foreach (GetAcctNum item in getAcctNum)
{
   _comboBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The getAcctNum

Comment: Try this `_comboBox.Text = _comboBox.Items.FindByText("text").Value`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign the list of account numbers to your `ComboBox`, specify which property to display to the user, and which to use as the underlying value of the selection.

```
List<GetAcctNum> accountNumbers = GetAccountNumbersFromWherever();

_comboBox.DataSource = accountNumbers;
_comboBox.DisplayMember = "Text";
_comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Then you can set the `SelectedValue` by specifying one of the values from your list of accounts.

```
_comboBox.SelectedValue = "SomeValueFromYourListOfAccounts";
```

Comment: I thought I tried this before, but somehow its working now.  I think its because i didn't override the ToString() earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Use this class and method to select item by value.

```
    public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public ComboboxItem(string text, string value)
        {
            Text = text;
            Value = value;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }


    private  void SelectCmbItemByValue( ComboBox cbo, string value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cbo.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            ComboboxItem ci = (ComboboxItem)cbo.Items[i];
            string _value = ci.Value.ToString();
            if (ci != null && _value == value)
            {
                cbo.SelectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: not working... Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'ComboboxItem'.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the ComboBox.Item to a `KeyValuePair<int, string>` :

```
private void SetCurrentValueOfComboBox(ComboBox oBox, string sItemValue)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < oBox.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    //Cast to KVP
                    KeyValuePair<int, string> oItem = (KeyValuePair<int,string>)oBox.Items[i];
    
                    if (oItem.Value == sItemValue)
                    {
                        oBox.SelectedItem = oBox.Items[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```